# Newbie: How do I put my original temperature in my output statement

Tags: java

```
     // TODO code application logic here
    String name; // city name
    double temperature; // degrees of temperature

    // declare an instance of Scanner to read the datastream from the keyboard.
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get name of city
    System.out.println ("Hello, please enter name of city: ");
    name = kb.nextLine();

    // get temperature in Celsius
    System.out.println("Please enter current temperature in " + name + " in degrees celsius");
    temperature = kb.nextDouble();

    // convert to degrees Fahrenheit
    temperature = ((temperature *9/5)+32);

    // output statement
     System.out.println(" The current temperature in " + name + " is " + temperature);
}
```

My output statement should read: The current temperature in London is 20 ⁰C, which is 68 ⁰F

How do I add the original Celsius temperature before the conversion into my output statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this,

```
// convert to degrees Fahrenheit
double temperatureInF = ((temperature *9/5)+32);

// output statement
 System.out.println(" The current temperature in " + name + " is " + temperature + ", which is " + temperatureInF);
```

---

Please go through a basic Java tutorial.
One is found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second variable that is a copy of the pre-conversion temperature.

```
celsiusTemperature = temperature;
temperature = ((temperature *9/5)+32);
```

And use celsiusTemperature in an appropriate output statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using same variable use 2 different variable for temperature

Answer (score -1):

```
// TODO code application logic here
    String name; // city name
    double temperature; // degrees of temperature

    // declare an instance of Scanner to read the datastream from the keyboard.
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get name of city
    System.out.println ("Hello, please enter name of city: ");
    name = kb.nextLine();

    // get temperature in Celsius
    System.out.println("Please enter current temperature in " + name + " in degrees celsius");
    temperature = kb.nextDouble();

    // convert to degrees Fahrenheit
    double fTemperature = ((temperature *9/5)+32);

    // output statement
     System.out.println(" The current temperature in " + name + " is " + temperature+", which is "+fTemperature );
```